# What is the name of this mechanical linkage?

Tags: joint, identification

[image]

I am trying to find a joint like these for a robot I'm building. It is often called a swivel joint or a universal joint, but with a modified spider. I can't find one anywhere and would prefer not to make it. Searching for 'universal joint' returns the standard automotive type. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I can't see any motion difference between them. So, what's the difference?

Comment: Why don't you modify your design to use a joint that's readily available in stores, then?

Answer (score 2):

Another name is pin and block - [mcmaster carr](http://www.mcmaster.com/#) is a go to place for many different fasteners, and mechanical doo-dads

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can find are [this](http://www.1mta.com/products/386/) and [this](http://www.c-rmfg.com/cnc-machining-aluminum-swivwl-joint.html): "Swivel Joint".